# В каких задачах применяются типы Memory и Span?

Tags: .net

Сравнительно недавно платформа .NET обзавелась 2-мя новыми типами:
`Memory` и `Span`.

Сходу я что-то не могу найти для них применения и собственно интересует в каких задачах они применяются?

Comment: Вот есть [статья](https://habr.com/ru/company/clrium/blog/420051/) на хабре, там в конце приведено пару примеров, где подходят данные типы